# how to organize the large number of class members?

Tags: c++, class, member

Suppose for a C++ class, there are 100 or even 1000 class private members of different types or classes. What's the neat way to organize that? It's not a good practice to scroll down/up the screen to do any operations.

Thanks so much!

Comment: 1) break the big classes into smaller ones, each "does one thing and does it well" 2) limit the scope of each variable to "smallest possible".

Comment: Looking a 10,000 line class sucks because it should suck.

Comment: Small classes. Small methods.

Comment: I agree with the above. With even 100 private members, it raises a red flag that the class may be a monolith of sort. I find the Single Responsibility Principle to be a good guiding light in these situations.

Comment: Then you should factor the class.

Comment: Also, in case that is just not in the cards at the moment because of refactoring a such, you are able to split a C++ class across multiple header files.

Comment: Here are some ideas [Fear Of Adding Classes](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FearOfAddingClasses).

Answer (score 0):

Basically one .h file should include just one class. But you can include nested class for instance. Then you can put the implementation in as many .cpp files as you want. Each file should be grouped into directories.

However you should consider a refactoring of your design if you have:

- too high level of abstraction, (classes too generic hence many methods).
- overuse of inheritance against aggregation.

This situations causes code bloat, that is more code than you really need.